# how can i adjust image and text side by side

Tags: java, android, xml

As the image in the link, how can I adjust image and text side by side so it adjusts accordingly with varied screen sizes and the remaining text goes to next line? 
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure there is a general solution here, but you can certainly use a `LinearLayout` with a horizontal orientation, and then add an image and a textview into it.  This, in turn, would be contained within another `LinearLayout` in vertical mode.

Comment: Tried that part but it didn't work out well for different screen sizes.

Answer (score 0):

also Use [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) if simple text or image than. create layout in `html` or load in [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: Nope. This is not perfect answer.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Can you provide with a solution I am not getting the correct approach to it.

Comment: @PamarNaresh I am not allowed to do it through web view and html didn't work out.